# Invoke Event from Button Disable

Tags: c#, events, invoke

Usually use this code for invoker the event from controller ex: button

```
button7.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button7_Click);
```

or

```
button7.PerfomClick();
```

but if the button is disable not work and i need call the event even if disabled, it is possible?

Comment: How about calling `this.button7_Click(this, new EventArgs());`?

Comment: Your first code segment *subscribes* to the event. The second code segment eventually *raises* the event. Because of this discrepancy I find your question unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PerformClick` won't work for disable button. Instead of `PerformClick`, you can call the handler directly.

```
button7_Click(button7, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Answer (score 1):

An event handler is nothing more than a function, so you could call it directly.